# Why does width % on flex-container shrink past its contents, but flex-basis does not?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have been playing around with the flex-box and have been trying to understand how it works. I have noticed that a % width for the flex-container will shrink past its contents, however if I swap width for flex-basis it overrides the percentage and stops it from shrinking past its contents. See the below example and replace 'width' with 'flex-basis':

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .flex-container {
      display: flex;
      background-color: DodgerBlue;
    }
    
    .flex-container > div {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      margin: 2px;
      padding: 2px;
      font-size: 30px;
      width: 20%;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h1>Create a Flex Container</h1>
    
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div>Item 1</div>
      <div>Item 2</div>
      <div>Item 3</div>  
    </div>
    
    <p>A Flexible Layout must have a parent element with the <em>display</em> property set to <em>flex</em>.</p>
    
    <p>Direct child elements(s) of the flexible container automatically becomes flexible items.</p>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

As far as I am aware the min-width: auto property should kick in and prevent the flex-item from shrinking past its min-content however this only works for flex-basis and not the width even though min-width is supposed to override both. Could someone please explain what is going on here? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand this you need to consider two concepts: The "flex base size" and the "main size".

It's a bit tricky to explain but if you refer to the full algorithm in [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#algo-main-item) You will notice that we first calculate the "flex base size" and later we calculate the "hypothetical main size" which is the final size.

For the "hypothetical main size":

> The **hypothetical main size** is the item’s **flex base size** clamped according to its used **min and max main sizes** (and flooring the content box size at zero).

When you use `width` you are affecting the "main sizes" that is used to define the *final width* (the "hypothetical main size"). In other words, it's not only the `min-width` that is responsible of the non-shrinking effect but it's the "min max main sizes".

Here is another example to better understand:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 30px;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
</div>
```

In the above, the items cannot shrink past `40px` defined in the `width`.

If you don't define `width`,`min-width` and `max-width`, the browser will automatically define the "min max mains sizes" based on the content but if you give explicit values they will be considered in the algorithm.

---

It may sounds a bit strange but if you think about it's logical. `flex-basis` define "only" an initial size that can be affected by other factors to define the final one. When using `width` or `height` we are defining the sizes.

Comment: I think I get what you are saying, But my question was why does min-width not override the width? I thought min-width: auto meant the min-content of the flex-item, meaning neither flex-basis nor width could shrink it further. So does min-width not compute to min-content when the width is not auto?

Comment: @MyssaMyssa it's not *only* min-width, this is what I am trying to explain. it's the "min main size". The algorithm is more complex than just min-width. Please read my answer again, I am explaining this part clearly.

Comment: Oh so width has the opportunity to reduce the min main size further, but min-width is there as an initial capping point should the width not be lower?

Comment: @MyssaMyssa it's not the min-width. if you **don't set** min-width,width or max-width there is a default configuration of "min/max size". If you **set** min-width,width or max-width you override this configuration. The "min main size" is the key of that behavior not the min-width property. min-width property allow you to control it